# Deploying contents from Author to Publisher automatically using Jenkins - CI

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, aem

I am automating a project which uses Adobe CQ5 technology using Jenkins - Continuous integration. My CI jobflow is as follows : CQ5 Build - > CQ5 Deploy - Author -> CQ5 Deploy - Publisher.

But my problem here is , my CQ5 Build will clone the code from the git repo and then will deploy in the CQ5 author which is fine, but i need to take the deployed content from the author and push it to the publisher and deploy it in the publisher.  IS there any provision in jenkins to do that?  Will writing a script work here ? Any suggestions please.

Comment: Are both Author and Publisher jobs on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

[Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) is what you might be looking for. It allows you to specify the job from which you want to copy the content. If the Author & Publisher jobs/projects are on different machine, you can use [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)

There are few other plugins as well which might be of some interest however, i feel the above one should suffice:
1. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin
2. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin